# Getting CURL error when using rasterio on Google App Engine

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, google, google-cloud

I'm attempting to get the pixel value of a raster that stored in an S3 bucket via a script that's using Flask and is hosted on Google's App Engine. If I run the script on my local machine, everything works fine. When I attempt to deploy the script to GAE, it deploys fine, but the web app does not work. I believe it has something to do with the AWS access keys. I have them in my app.yaml as such:

```
env_variables: 
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'my-key-id'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'my-secret-key-id'
```

I've also tried setting the variables in the actual python script using:

```
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = secret_access_key
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = access_key
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line 216,
in rasterio._base.DatasetBase.__init__ File "rasterio/_shim.pyx", line 67,
in rasterio._shim.open_dataset File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line 205,
in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_pointer rasterio._err.CPLE_HttpResponseError: 
CURL error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
```

Can anyone see why this error is being thrown or has anyone used rasterio in GAE before?

Comment: I don't use GAE, so can't be any more specific than it sounds like you may need to figure out where the CA certs are in GAE, and tell the curl library where they are https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1737#issuecomment-524001890 https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio#ssl-certs

Comment: do you know if CA certs are "Certificate Authority certs" or does that mean something else?

Comment: Yes Certificate Authority (CA) certificates

Comment: @user2856 I tried that in the python code and tried adding it as an env_variable in the .yaml and the same error returns. I also tried another path that i had found online of "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" with no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rasterio` 1.1.8](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/f3c04a5b7d20354e75e86c57cb01df46e5ee325c/CHANGES.txt#L9) now depends on [`certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/):

> - If the certifi package can be imported, its certificate store location will   be passed to GDAL during import of rasterio._env
> unless CURL_CA_BUNDLE is   already set ([#2009](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/2009)).

So updating rasterio should fix your `CURL error: error setting certificate` problem.

If you can't update, but you can install `certifi`, you could try [something like](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/2009#issuecomment-706628630):

```
rasterio.Env(CURL_CA_BUNDLE=certifi.where())
```

Or from a comment by [StefanBrand_EOX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/122597/stefanbrand-eox):

```
os.environ.setdefault("CURL_CA_BUNDLE", certifi.where())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Credit to @snowman who proposed [#2009](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/2009)

Comment: I have installed rasterio 1.1.8 and cannot get rid of this error, unfortunately. I have GDAL 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Ok, sorry, this is not GAE, of course.

Comment: This actually works for me: `os.environ.setdefault("CURL_CA_BUNDLE", certifi.where())`